# What is this bug with a hundred feet that I found in my garden?

Tags: identification, bugs

This bug was crawling between my pot garden this morning. Can anyone tell me what it is?
(Im sorry for the bluryness, it moves so fast!

[image]
[image]

Comment: As that idiot says, a centipede. To find the species name though, we may need your location so we can pin-point species.

Comment: These bugs are so common, the best thing to do is freak out and feel the numbness in your face when you see all those legs so close together

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks to be some kind of [centipede](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centipede), but I couldn't venture a guess at the species.

Comment: Most likely Lithobius forficatus, the garden centipede, but hard to be certain without a close up, and it'd need to be dead to keep it still!